# R: fast (conditional) subsetting where feasible

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I would like to subset rows of my data

```
library(data.table); set.seed(333); n <- 100
dat <- data.table(id=1:n, x=runif(n,100,120), y=runif(n,200,220), z=runif(n,300,320))

> head(dat)
   id        x        y        z
1:  1 109.3400 208.6732 308.7595
2:  2 101.6920 201.0989 310.1080
3:  3 119.4697 217.8550 313.9384
4:  4 111.4261 205.2945 317.3651
5:  5 100.4024 212.2826 305.1375
6:  6 114.4711 203.6988 319.4913
```

in several stages. I am aware that I could apply `subset(.)` sequentially to achieve this.

```
> s <- subset(dat, x>119)
> s <- subset(s, y>219)
> subset(s, z>315)
   id        x        y        z
1: 55 119.2634 219.0044 315.6556
```

My problem is that I need to automate this and it might happen that the subset is empty. In this case, I would want to skip the step(s) that result in an empty set. For example, if my data was

```
dat2 <- dat[1:50]
> s <-subset(dat2,x>119)
> s
   id        x        y        z
1:  3 119.4697 217.8550 313.9384
2: 50 119.2519 214.2517 318.8567
```

the second step `subset(s, y>219)` would come up empty but I would still want to apply the third step `subset(s,z>315)`. Is there a way to apply a subset-command only if it results in a non-empty set? I imagine something like `subset(s, y>219, nonzero=TRUE)`. I would want to avoid constructions like

```
s <- dat
if(nrow(subset(s, x>119))>0){s <- subset(s, x>119)}
if(nrow(subset(s, y>219))>0){s <- subset(s, y>219)}
if(nrow(subset(s, z>318))>0){s <- subset(s, z>319)}
```

because I fear the if-then jungle would be rather slow, especially since I need to apply all of this to different data.tables within a list using `lapply(.)`. That's why I am hoping to find a solution optimized for speed.

PS. I only chose `subset(.)` for clarity, solutions with e.g. data.table would be just as welcome if not more so.

Comment: Why not use data.table methods ` dat[x > 119 & y > 219]` if the initial dataset is `data.table`

Comment: Does this ignore elements of the condition that would result in empty sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Konrad's answer that this should throw a warning or at least report what happens somehow. Here's a data.table way that will take advantage of indices (see package vignettes for details):

```
f = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE){
  L   = substitute(list(...))[-1]
  mon = data.table(cond = as.character(L))[, skip := FALSE]

  for (i in seq_along(L)){
    d = eval( substitute(x[cond, verbose=v], list(cond = L[[i]], v = verbose)) )
    if (nrow(d)){
      x = d
    } else {
      mon[i, skip := TRUE]
    }    
  }
  print(mon)
  return(x)
}
```

Usage

```
> f(dat, x > 119, y > 219, y > 1e6)
        cond  skip
1:   x > 119 FALSE
2:   y > 219 FALSE
3: y > 1e+06  TRUE
   id        x        y        z
1: 55 119.2634 219.0044 315.6556
```

The verbose option will print extra info provided by data.table package, so you can see when indices are being used. For example, with `f(dat, x == 119, verbose=TRUE)`, I see it.

> because I fear the if-then jungle would be rather slow, especially since I need to apply all of this to different data.tables within a list using lapply(.).

If it's for non-interactive use, maybe better to have the function return `list(mon = mon, x = x)` to more easily keep track of what the query was and what happened. Also, the verbose console output could be captured and returned.

Comment: definitely a way to go if speed matters. Use of indices can be easily checked using `options("datatable.verbose"=TRUE)`.

Comment: This way appears to be somewhat faster than the tidyverse one, thanks!

Comment: One follow-up question: Is there a way of applying `f(.)` to different groups within a data.table? In my actual problem, `dat` also contains a grouping variable and I would like to apply `f(.)` to `dat` but use for each group the cutoff in a separate data.table `c`. Any idea, or should I post as separate question? sample data: `library(data.table); set.seed(333); n <- 100; dat <- data.table(id=1:n, group=rep(1:2,each=n/2), x=runif(n,100,120), y=runif(n,200,220), z=runif(n,300,320)); c <- data.table(group=1:2, x=c(110,119), y=c(210,219), z=c(310,319))`

Comment: @bumblebee I think maybe a new question would make sense. I wrote my answer assuming interactive use (typing in `y > 10` etc) but under your extension, I'd expect a very different approach would make sense (to do it programmatically) and others might have better ideas about it.

Comment: 5min was optimistic, but it is now here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465187/r-group-wise-conditional-subsetting-where-feasible

Answer (score 3):

An interesting approach could be developed using modified `filter` function offered in `dplyr`. In case of conditions not being met the `non_empty_filter` filter function returns original data set.

## Notes

- IMHO, this is fairly non-standard behaviour and should be reported via `warning`. Of course, this can be removed and has no bearing on the function results.

## Function

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang) # enquo
non_empty_filter <- function(df, expr) {
    expr <- enquo(expr)

    res <- df %>% filter(!!expr)

    if (nrow(res) > 0) {
        return(res)
    } else {
        # Indicate that filter is not applied
        warning("No rows meeting conditon")
        return(df)
    }
}
```

## Condition met

*Behaviour:* Returning one row for which the condition is met.

```
dat %>%
    non_empty_filter(x > 119 & y > 219)
```

### Results

```
# id        x        y        z
# 1 55 119.2634 219.0044 315.6556
```

## Condition not met

*Behaviour:* Returning the full data set as the whole condition is not met due to `y > 1e6`.

```
dat %>%
    non_empty_filter(x > 119 & y > 219 & y > 1e6)
```

### Results

```
# id        x        y        z
# 1:   1 109.3400 208.6732 308.7595
# 2:   2 101.6920 201.0989 310.1080
# 3:   3 119.4697 217.8550 313.9384
# 4:   4 111.4261 205.2945 317.3651
# 5:   5 100.4024 212.2826 305.1375
# 6:   6 114.4711 203.6988 319.4913
# 7:   7 112.1879 209.5716 319.6732
# 8:   8 106.1344 202.2453 312.9427
# 9:   9 101.2702 210.5923 309.2864
# 10:  10 106.1071 211.8266 301.0645
```

## Condition met/not met one-by-one

*Behaviour:* Skipping filter that would return an empty data set.

```
dat %>%
    non_empty_filter(y > 1e6) %>% 
    non_empty_filter(x > 119) %>% 
    non_empty_filter(y > 219)
```

### Results

```
# id        x        y        z
# 1 55 119.2634 219.0044 315.6556
```