# variables not recognized in for-loop nested within lapply

Tags: r, nested, data.table, lapply

I have the following data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- list(data.table(id=1:10, group=rep(1:2, each=5), x=rnorm(10)), 
            data.table(id=1:10, group=rep(1:2, each=5), x=rnorm(10)))
```

to which I would like to apply this function element by element and group by group.

```
subs = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE){
  L   = substitute(list(...))[-1]
  mon = data.table(cond = as.character(L))[, skip := FALSE]

  for (i in seq_along(L)){
    d = eval( substitute(x[cond, verbose=v], list(cond = L[[i]], v = verbose)) )
    if (nrow(d)){
      x = d
    } else {
      mon[i, skip := TRUE]
    }    
  }
  #print(mon)
  return(x)
}
```

However, when I run this code

```
# works
out <- lapply(1:2, function(h){
    res <- list()
    d <- dat[[h]] 
    for(k in 1:2){
        g <- d[group==k]
        cutoff <- 1
        print(cutoff)
        res[[k]] <- subs(g, x>cutoff)
    }
    res
})
```

I receive the error that object `cutoff` cannot be found, although it is printed correctly. However, when I apply the same for-loop outside of the `lapply()`, it appears to work.

```
d1 <- dat[[1]]
s <- list()
for(k in 1:2){
    g <- d1[group==k]
    cutoff <- 1
    s[[k]] <- subs(g, x>cutoff)
}

> s
[[1]]
   id group        x
1:  1     1 1.370958

[[2]]
   id group        x
1:  7     2 1.511522
2:  9     2 2.018424
```

This leads me to suspect that it's the inclusion in the `lapply()` that causes the error but I find it hard to see what the error is, let along how to fix it.

**Edit**

Data with two variables:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- list(data.table(id=1:10, group=rep(1:2, each=5), x=rnorm(10), y=11:20), 
            data.table(id=1:10, group=rep(1:2, each=5), x=rnorm(10), y=11:20))
```

with expected result

```
[[1]]
   id group          x   y
1:  9     2  2.0184237  19
2:  1     1  1.3709584  11
3:  2     1 -0.5646982  12
4:  3     1  0.3631284  13
5:  4     1  0.6328626  14
6:  5     1  0.4042683  15

[[2]]
   id group          x   y
1:  2     1  2.2866454  12
2: 10     2  1.3201133  20
```

Comment: I think your function `subs()` is not aware of the object `cutoff`, as you're not passing it trough arguments. `Substitute` returns parse tree, but doesn't create cutoff?

`subs = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE, cutoff = cutoff)` and 
 `res[[k]] <- subs(g, 1 > cutoff, cutoff = cutoff)` would, for example, work

edit: outside the lapply ou create it in global env. which `sub()` can access there?

Comment: Correct, `subs()` passes `x>cutoff` as it's to L not `x>1`, insert `browser()` at the first line of `subs()` and re run the code.

Comment: @Arcoutte, I don't quite understand. If possible, I would like to keep the conditions entered as flexible as possible so I can apply `subs()` to different situations. Are you saying I have to define variables in the definition of the function?

Comment: I checked and think you are right: It creates a global variable. I still don't understand how to do it within `lapply()`.

Comment: Change `L` in `subs` to `L=list(...)` and `res[[k]]` to `res[[k]] <- subs(g, substitute(x>cutoff))`,Works fine for one and two conditions in `subs` but I don't know if it will scale to your real case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use non-standard evaluation you always pay a price. Here it is a scoping issue.

It works like this:

```
subs = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE){
  L   = substitute(list(...))[-1]
  mon = data.table(cond = as.character(L))[, skip := FALSE]

  for (i in seq_along(L)){
    d = eval( substitute(x[cond,, #needed to add this comma, don't know why
                           verbose=v], list(cond = L[[i]], v = verbose)))
    if (nrow(d)){
      x = d
    } else {
      mon[i, skip := TRUE]
    }    
  }
  #print(mon)
  return(x)
}

out <- lapply(1:2, function(h){
  res <- list()
  d <- dat[[h]] 
  for(k in 1:2){
    g <- d[group==k]

    cutoff <- 1
    res[[k]] <- eval(substitute(subs(g, x>cutoff), list(cutoff = cutoff)))
  }
  res
})
#works
```

Is there a particular reason for not using data.table's `by` parameter?

**Edit:**

> Background: The point of subs() is to apply multiple conditions (if
>   multiple are passed to it) unless one would result in an empty subset.

I would use a different approach then:

```
subs = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE){
  L   = substitute(list(...))[-1]

  for (i in seq_along(L)){
    d = eval( substitute(x[cond, , verbose=v], list(cond = L[[i]], v = verbose)))
    x <- rbind(d, x[!d, on = "group"]) 
  }

  return(x)
}

out <- lapply(dat, function(d){

  cutoff <- 2 #to get empty groups

  eval(substitute(subs(d, x>cutoff), list(cutoff = cutoff)))

})

#[[1]]
#   id group          x
#1:  9     2  2.0184237
#2:  1     1  1.3709584
#3:  2     1 -0.5646982
#4:  3     1  0.3631284
#5:  4     1  0.6328626
#6:  5     1  0.4042683
#
#[[2]]
#   id group          x
#1:  2     1  2.2866454
#2:  6     2  0.6359504
#3:  7     2 -0.2842529
#4:  8     2 -2.6564554
#5:  9     2 -2.4404669
#6: 10     2  1.3201133
```

Beware that this does not retain the ordering.

Another option that retains the ordering:

```
subs = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE){
  L   = substitute(list(...))[-1]

  for (i in seq_along(L)){
    x = eval( substitute(x[, {
      res <- .SD[cond];
      if (nrow(res) > 0) res else .SD 
    }, by = "group", verbose=v], list(cond = L[[i]], v = verbose)))
  }

  return(x)
}
```

The `by` variable could be passed as a function parameter and then substituted in together with the condition.

I haven't done benchmarks comparing the efficiency of these two.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how to use `[..., by=group]` together with `subs()`
? I am all ears! Also: Is the `drop=FALSE` necessary? I thought I read data.table made this obsolete.

Comment: Sorry, artifacts from testing.

Comment: Can you change `subs`? Then just pass a value that is then passed on to `by`.

Comment: Background: The point of  `subs()` is to apply multiple conditions (if multiple are passed to it) unless one would result in an empty subset. It was Frank's solution to [an earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430411/r-fast-conditional-subsetting-where-feasible). As long as it retains this feature, it can be changed. I would welcome this even, since the for-loop over groups is not ideal.

Comment: Excellent! To improve on your edit, I wonder whether `subs = function(x, by, ..., verbose=FALSE){... grouping = as.character(by) ... by = as.character(grouping) ...}`, where `by` picks up the grouping variable would work. Does this make sense?

Comment: Also, can you sketch how one would add a second variable? I have added data with two variables in the OP. Somehow, `cut1 <- 1; cut2 <- 18; eval(substitute(subs(d, "group", x>cut1, y>cut2, list(cut1 = cut1, cut2=cut2))))` does not work.

Comment: @bumblebee Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. The >1 variable case still does not work the way I thought it would. How does it work now?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I have added data with two variables, `x` and `y`, to the OP. I wonder how to apply your new approach with two variables. I have tried `cut1 <- 1; cut2 <- 18; eval(substitute(subs(d, x>cut1, y>cut2, list(cut1=cut1, cut2=cut2)))) ` but it doesn’t work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? An error? An unexpected result (what is the expected result)?

Comment: It gives an error: "Object 'X' not found". I added the expected result to the OP.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the error. Maybe just the wrong parenthesis in your comment above? But that should give a different error.

Comment: Apologies, works for me, too. However, the result is incorrect. For `[[2]]`, it falsely returns ID 9, for which only condition 2 is correct, whereas condition 1 is not met (`x =-2.44 < 1`), although there is an observation in the same group that fulfills both conditions.

Comment: @bumblebee My solution does this: (1) Subset with first condition. If result is empty, continue with full dataset. (2) Subset with second condition. If result is empty, return result from previous step. Are you saying, you want this instead: Subset with both conditions. If result is empty, return original dataset.

Comment: Apparently not, as that doesn't explain the result from the second data.table. You really need to define your algorithm more clearly. I can't infer it from the expected result.

Comment: Alright, funny. So, you say at (2), it subsets the _original_ set with second condition. I would like it to subset the outcome of (1) by applying condition 2. This way, the set becomes smaller and smaller, the more conditions are applied, until one would reduce it to size zero. Then this condition is left out and the next condition is tried.

Comment: Yes, that's what my code *is* doing. But that algo doesn't produce your expected result. I'm at a loss here ...

Comment: I wonder whether it actually does that. It outputs an ID for which condition 1 is not fulfilled. This should only happen when there is no ID that fulfills cond1. But there is one that fulfills both cond1 and cond2. This leads me to believe that your algo somehow treats the conditions independently.

Comment: Please run `lapply(dat, function(d){
  cut1 <- 1; cut2 <- 18;
  eval(substitute(subs(d, x>cut1, y>cut2), list(cut1=cut1, cut2=cut2)))
})` with the last version of `subs` and tell me exactly for which group in which data.frame the result is wrong and why.

Comment: I apologize sincerely for stealing your time. It appears that I was using different data than the one above. It works just fine. Thanks a million, again. Will delete comments later so as not to confuse others.