# Use string representation of variable in i for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Apparently I am too stupid to enter the correct search terms, b/c I think that my question is not unique at all.

How to refer to a variable by string in the `i` part of `data.table`? `with` and `..x` are all good for the `j` part, but what would be the equivalent in the `i` part? Do I have to use evil `eval` (pun intended ;)

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:4, y = 4:1)

my_filter_fun <- function(var = names(dt)) {
  var <- match.arg(var)
  dt[eval(parse(text = paste(var, "== 1")))]
}
my_filter_fun("x")
my_filter_fun("y")
```

What is the idiomatic way in `data.table` to do so? Coming from `dplyr` I think I am looking for the equivalent of quosures for `data.table`?

Bonus question: how could i implement `my_filter_fun` such that such a call

```
my_filter_fun(x > 1)
```

would return the same result as

```
dt[x > 1]
```

Comment: might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia/54800108#54800108 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1191259%20substitute

Comment: Wow, a great read. Totally immersed into all the links from that post. It does answer a  lot f my other questions too and also questions I did not even have yet :) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, I suggest using `get()` to avoid the evil of `eval()`:

```
my_filter_fun <- function(var = names(dt)) {
  var <- match.arg(var)
  dt[get(var) == 1]
}
my_filter_fun("x")
   x y
1: 1 4
```

For the bonus question, you *could* do the following. It can be simplified though - just that I don't know how.

```
bonus_filter_fun <- function(filter) {
  filter <- deparse(substitute(filter))
  dt[eval(parse(text = filter))]
}
bonus_filter_fun(x > 1)
   x y
1: 2 3
2: 3 2
3: 4 1
```

Comment: Perfect! It is still a bit mind-boggling to me to use `data.table` efficiently in functions (being more of a `dplyr` guy myself - and there quasiquotation solves most of the probs)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432125/1989480. Hence, maybe something like `bonus_filter_fun <- function(iexpr) {
    eval(substitute(dt[cond], list(cond=substitute(iexpr))))
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use esoteric R magic, but not `eval`. 
What you are asking about is `NSE` or non-standard evaluation.  Here's an example similar to yours:

```
theDf <- tibble(Sticks = 4:7, Stones = 9:12)
#' @title Create a new column by adding 8 to one of the existing columns.
a8Col <- function(df, newName, existName){
  existName <- enquo(existName)
  df %>%
    mutate(!! newName := !! existName + 8L )
}

R > a8Col(theDf, "Bones", Sticks)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
Sticks Stones Bones
<int>  <int> <int>
1      4      9    12
2      5     10    13
3      6     11    14
4      7     12    15
R > a8Col(theDf, "Bones", Stones)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
Sticks Stones Bones
<int>  <int> <int>
1      4      9    17
2      5     10    18
3      6     11    19
4      7     12    20
```

Notice that I didn't have to put quotes around `Sticks` or `Stones` in the calls to `a8Col`.

NSE is a hard topic.  Hadley Wickham has written two chapter on it, (`Quasiquotation` and `Evaluation`) in his "[Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/)" book.

Comment: Thanks,. This is, however, `dplyr` syntax which I am very well aware of. What I am asking is to do the same in `data.table` though.